# redirect in .htaccess (from do.m/a/i/n to do.m/n)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Me need redirect like:

```
From:
domain.com/first/second/third 
To:
domain.com/third
```

But ONLY if we will have word "**first**", as first sub-domain.

> Real link:
>   http://id.factor.ua/root/nalogiibuhychet/nalogi-i-buhgalterskiy-uchet
>
> I want redirect to: http://id.factor.ua/nalogi-i-buhgalterskiy-uchet

if I doing the next: `RewriteRule ^root/.*/(.*)$  $1 [L,R=301]` server redirect me to domain page `http://id.factor.ua/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com

    # [...] Other directives  

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^root/.*/(.*)/?$  $1 [L,R=301]

    # [...] Other directives  

</VirtualHost>
```

The above rewrite rule will trigger only if the you have "root" as your first subdomain, and will redirect to your last subdomain

[DEMO](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)

Comment: @serge please check the demo link in my answer. You can test your rewrite rule there

Comment: thx u! But I doing it like the next code `RewriteRule ^root/(.*)/(.*)/?$  $2 [L,R=301]` and it working!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rule you need :

```
RewriteRule ^first/\w+/(\w+)/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Will work for :

- domain.com/first/second/third
- domain.com/first/second/third/
- domain.com/first/second/bar
- domain.com/first/foo/bar

Comment: Where are you putting your `.htaccess` ?

Comment: thank you! But I doing it like the next code `RewriteRule ^root/(.*)/(.*)/?$  $2 [L,R=301]` and it working!!!